# Failure Vs. Inability

Tags: style

Only one painting by Van Gogh was sold during his lifetime. What would be the best sentence to describe that?

1) He could sell only one painting during his lifetime.

2) He couldn't sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

3) He succeeded to sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

4) He was able to sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

Comment: This sounds like it was copied from a test.

Comment: Mr @Scimonster It wasn't copied from any test. I'm thinking to best way to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) He could sell only one painting during his lifetime.

This is the clearest sentence of the four you posted. It might also be interpreted that someone or something was forbidding him from selling any more.

"He was only able to sell one painting during his lifetime" speaks more directly about his ability.

> 2) He couldn't sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

This is understandable, but writing "only one" is clearer than writing "not more than one".

> 3) He succeeded to sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

"He succeeded to sell" doesn't work together. "He succeeded in selling ... more than one painting" - no, that says the opposite of what you want it to say.

> 4) He was able to sell more than one painting during his lifetime.

This is understandable, but it says the opposite of what you want to say.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think picking (1) would be the best.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but I think it's worth mentioning what the _could_ implies. "He sold only one painting during his lifetime" is not quite the same as, "He _could_ sell only one painting during his lifetime." The latter implies an effort was made to sell more than one; the former might be more appropriate if there wasn't a heavy effort to sell more than one painting.